# Подскажите, пожалуйста, расшифровку GNU

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, unix

Я знаю, что есть такая "GNU's not Unix", но что означает буква G?

Comment: [GNU](https://yandex.kz/yandsearch?clid=1923018&text=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%20GNU&rdrnd=240857&lr=35393&redircnt=1580645739.1)

Comment: читаем сам первоисточник: [Название “GNU” — это рекурсивное сокращение фразы “GNU's Not Unix!” (“GNU — не Unix!”). “GNU” произносится как гну, одним слогом, как глагол “гнуть” в первом лице, единственном числе настоящего времени изъявительного наклонения.](https://www.gnu.org/)

Comment: Так это животное оказывается [Gnu's](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-gnus-wandering-gnu-wanderung-136949728.html)

Answer (score 1):

Так и расшифровывается "GNU Not Unix" это игра слов, у программистов это нередкое явление. Посмотрите расшифровку WINE, там похожая ситуация.

Comment: В WINE можно каждую букву расшифровать, а здесь нет.

Comment: WINE расшифровка "WINE - это не эмулятор" "WINE - Wine Is Not an Emulator"

Comment: Что-бы понять рекурсию, нужно понять рекурсию. ©

Answer (score 1):

GNU - свободная Unix-подобная операционная система. Скорее всего название связано с логотипом проекта, так как на нем изображено животное, которое носит название Gnu (Гну).

Соответственно, название никак не расшифровывается, т.к это не аббревиатура.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]